# Как сделать несколько селектов из базы данных sql

Tags: java

Как сделать несколько селектов из одной базы данных, собственно получить все таблицы, помогите разобраться.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

А в чем проблема? Просто делаешь select для каждой таблицы в методе, а полученный результат в списки кладешь

Comment: ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery("select * from CANSELLEDCERTIFICATES");

Comment: ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery("select * from ................");

Comment: List<String> sql = new ArrayList<String>();

Comment: sql.add(resultSet);?

Comment: Просто в разных методах сделай это. Каждый метод будет возвращать список объектов из конкретной таблицы.

Comment: Я изменил код. Как сделать так чтобы выводились три таблицы?

Comment: https://github.com/steed777/inputjsondatabase/blob/master/src/main/java/convert/ResultSetConverter.java